# ScrollView не полностью прокручивает TableLayout

Tags: android, android-scrollview

У меня 40 кнопок, каждая из них должна создавать свой фрагмент. Прокрутка работает, но не всё помещается.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/TableLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button41"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="500dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="1" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button42"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="2" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button43"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="3" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button44"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="4" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button37"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="5" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button38"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="6" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button39"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="7" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button40"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="8" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button33"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="9" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button34"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="10" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button35"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="11" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button36"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="12" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button29"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="13" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button30"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="14" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button31"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="15" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button32"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="16" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button25"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="17" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button26"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="18" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button27"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="19" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button28"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="20" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button21"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="21" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button22"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="22" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button23"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="23" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button24"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="24" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="25" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="26" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="27" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="28" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="29" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="30" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="31" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="32" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="33" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="34" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="35" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button16"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="36" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button17"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="37" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button18"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="38" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button19"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="39" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button20"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="40" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавил глядя на советы по решению проблемы, но результата нет.

Comment: Выставьте высоту для `ScrollView` = `wrap_content`

Comment: попробовал, не помогает

Comment: Не знаю ваши задачи, но, вообще, так-то лучше использовать для таких целей `RecyclerView` + `GridLayoutManager`. И в коде проще и в `xml`

Comment: Да, я думал об этом, но у меня 40 кнопок, это как 40 билетов на вопросы. Я не знаю, как бы я смог их добавить в GridView. У меня нет определенного item, которые будут добавляться в зависимости от поступивших данных. 40 кнопок, каждая из которых должна слушаться в отдельном onClick

Comment: не `GridView`, `RecyclerView` с `GridLayoutManager`. Если у вас задача сделать 40 кнопок с ответами на вопросы - это самое то для вас. Посмотрите, делается очень просто (когда разберешься), экономит кучу времени и строк кода

Comment: Не совсем понял. вы говорите, что TableLayout самое то или Grid ?)

Comment: `RecyclerView` )

Comment: да, попробовал RecyclerView, он действительно позволяет сделать, то что мне нужно и не приходится сразу все 40 кнопок заранее устанавливать. Но и он тоже не без проблемы оказался,    в ViewHolder метод onClick вызывается, когда нажимаю рядом с кнопкой, а не на неё) надеюсь глупая ошибка где-то, пойду искать)

Comment: ну если обработчик вешать на кнопку внутри холдера - обычно такой проблемы нет. Проверьте. Если что-то не будет получаться, вы всегда можете задать новый вопрос ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавление `paddingBottom` в `ScrollView` разрешило эту проблему для меня:

```
 android:paddingBottom="<toolbar height in collapsed state>"
```

Так же решит проблему, если вы используете `NestedScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [NestedScrollView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/NestedScrollView) вместо `ScrollView`.

Comment: хорошо, что вы указали мне на NestedScrollView, я не знал про отличие, но проблему это не решает, у людей и с NestedScrollView встречается эта же проблема. Но я нашел причину